# How can the program structure reach Page_PreRender in a page of asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp page where I have 2 grid in which I have a Remark Textbox and a delete button in each row. When the Remark textbox is empty I run a server-side validation like this:

```
  {
    if (RemarkTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                BRMessengers.BRInformation(this, "Remarks Cannot Be left Empty.");
                return;
            }
            else
            { 
              if (Session["update"].ToString() == ViewState["update"].ToString())
                {
                    deleteReport(id);
                }
           }}
```

My problem is that when I run a page it executes well. When I delete the row without giving a remark then it should give a message, but here I don't get a message also. And not only that, the program control flow does not reach to the `Page_PreRender`. In another grid I have the same structure as mentioned above it runs well. I also have the `Page_PreRender` function and the sample is as follows:

```
    {  
     protected void Page_PreRender(object obj, EventArgs e)
     {
        ViewState["update"] = Session["update"];
     }
  }
```

Comment: Why is there a brace before and after your Page_PreRender event handler? Also, why are moving data back and forth between your Session and ViewState?

Comment: sir i have done to avoid the previous operation like delete or update. this was happening while refreshing the page.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete version of the code and the markup. There's not enough information to help you right now.

Comment: thank you  Marshall777 For your kind support. I Find the solution. Because of grid binding all this problem arises. when i try to bind the grid in finally block the problem is solved. Thank you for your kind effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the grid in Finally block. Binding of Grid creates a problem. Therefore, you should bind the grid as follows:

```
  {
   try
   {
    if (RemarkTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        BRMessengers.BRInformation(this, "Remarks Cannot Be left Empty.");
        return;
    }
    else
    { 
      if (Session["update"].ToString() == ViewState["update"].ToString())
        {
            deleteReport(id);
        }
   }
}
catch(Exception)
{
 BrMessanger.BrMessage(this,"server error. Please try again");
}
finally
{
  YourGridName.DataSource=loadDetails();
  YourGridName.DataBind();
}

}
```